# Cancel a Future and still retrieve its return value

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a recorder class that polls for values from a data source every n milliseconds. The whole this is supposed to run asynchronously and return a collection containing the recorded data.

My Idea was to have an ExecutorService with a single thread and a Callable that does the data polling. The callable is supposed to be interrupted, so the caller does not have to wait for any `Thread.sleep` calls to finish. To interrupt he Callable i call `Future.cancel(true)` on the Future returned from the ExecutorService:

```
class Recorder {
    private DataSource source;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Future<List<MyData>> dataFuture;

    private class FixedPollRateCallable {
        private DataSource source;
        private long pollrate;

        public FixedPollrateCallable(DataSource source, long pollrate) {
            this.source = source;
            this.pollrate = pollrate;
        }

        public List<MyData> call() throws Exception {
            List<MyData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                dataList.add(source.getData());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(pollrate);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            return dataList;
        }
    }

    public Recorder(DataSource source) {
        this.source = source;
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void startRecording(long pollrate) {
        if(dataFuture != null && !dataFuture.isDone())
            throw new RecordingException();

        dataFuture = executor.submit(new FixedPollRateCallable(source, pollrate);
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        dataFuture.cancel(true);
    }

    public List<MyData> getRecordedData() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return dataFuture.get();
    }
}
```

But when calling the whole thing like this:

```
recorder.startRecording();
recorder.stopRecording();
recorder.getRecordedData();
```

I get a `java.util.concurrent.CancellationException` on the `recorder.getRecordedData()` call.

I guess that besides interrupting the Thread, `cancel(true)` also sets a cancellation flag, so calls to `Future.get()` will always fail.

Is there any way around that, or do you know about a better alternative that allows me to interrupt a Thread, breaking out of `Thread.sleep()` and still being able to return a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you ask for something that conceptually does not make sense:

Lets quote the javadoc for [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()):

*Throws: CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled*

And for `cancel()` it says:

*After this method returns, subsequent calls to isDone() will always return true. Subsequent calls to isCancelled() will always return true if this method returned true.*

In other words: you probably need some other kind of mechanism here. For example, you could change your Runable to **push** the already collected information instead of returning it.

In other words: instead of using a Future to **get** all data at some point; why don't you simply send all data to a "safe sink" directly upon arrival? Your approach is to poll; but obviously: polling and interrupting do not go hand in hand!

Edit: right now you create your Recorder like this:

```
 public Recorder(DataSource source)
```

so you built to receive "data" from `source`. An easy solution could be to have

```
 public Recorder(DataSource source, List<MyData> sink)
```

as well.

And instead of keeping a local `dataList` in your Runable ... you simply append to the `sink` provided to the recorder.

Me using the word "safe" simply refers to the fact that need to pay attention when multiple threads start updating the same list for example.

Comment: I have never thought about it that way. Can you give me a couple pointers on what a "safe sink" is? I am new to concurrent programming in Java and it seems like a self-made solution almost always fails due to some race condition or caching error.

Comment: Ah, i understand. Since the Recorder class is a facade to the underlying multithread madness anyways, i can encapsulate the List "sink" so it is safe to get it after the poll-callable (or runnable in this case) is cancelled. Thank you very much!